# Nginx response error 404 when processing a specific url

Tags: nginx

I have updated my gems and I have lost my old nginx config. I´m setting a new config in nginx.conf. My new Nginx version is 1.17.3. The home page is loading and navigation from home is also right. But, if I directly type a specific url in my browser, Nginx responds a 404.

I don´t remember what I´m missing. My nginx.conf file:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    upstream api.development {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
        server unix:/tmp/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # set client body size to 10M #
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    gzip  on;


    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root   /path-to-root/app;
        index  index.html index.htm;

    # Proxy requests to backend API
        location /api {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_redirect off;
            rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://api.development;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Comment: what kind of url are you typing? you are defining a root path (I suppose for static content) but you don't define any location block for your static content ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just already got it by adding: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;`

My concern is that with this line it´s working on development environment, however, in production, I haven´t updated the server yet, and I don´t see that I have any try_files enabled in my config file. So´I don´t understand if this is what I should do. I´m not skilled at all in nginx config.